# MKMapView in UITabBarController using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, mkmapview

I'm learning to put a map inside a tab bar in my iOS apps using swift.
Starting with login page as "View Controller", then continue to MainMenu as "Tab Bar Controller", and as it first tab is mainMap as "MKMapView" under "MapController".

In the beginning, when I run the apps, it can normally login, and then show the map normally. Unfortunately, when I try to control the map view (adding annotation, setting the region, etc.), it always crashed (Signal SIGABRT).

this is my code in MapController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mainMap: MKMapView!

var manager:CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    var latitude  : CLLocationDegrees = 140.997086
    var longitude : CLLocationDegrees = 43.204067

    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    var homeSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)

    var homeLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    var theRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(homeLocation, homeSpan)

    mainMap.setRegion(theRegion, animated: false)

    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = homeLocation

    annotation.title = "test"

    annotation.subtitle = "another test"

    mainMap.addAnnotation(annotation)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

}
```

can anyone help me with this issue? if you have other sample, it also will be very nice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the crash message? Which line does it crash on?

Comment: which one is crash message? if I add mainMap.setRegion, it always crash.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line and check that `mainMap` isn't nil

Comment: After I used breakpoint on that line, I can't find 'mainMap'.

Comment: You should be able to type 'po mainmap' or possibly 'po self.mainmap' in the debugger console and it should appear in the list of variables on the bottom left - you may need to expand "self"

Comment: thank you so much, @Paulw11. you really help me fix my problem.
it's not about my swift code, but it's about my missunderstanding about "latitude" and "longitude".

thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working perfectly, except the value of latitude and longitude.